# Node JS: In POST call, the HOST NAME not accepting the 'http://'

Tags: node.js, http-post

I am trying to make an POST call in node JS using the HEADERS, BODY. While i tried in Chrome "Advanced Rest Client" posted the URL with Request Headers, Body etc and i got the response message as 200 OK.

but the same request i tried in node js as given below

```
http.request({
     host: "http://somesite.com",
     path: "/path/name/",
     port: 80
     method: "POST"
     ...
})
```

when i run it, i get the following error

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://somesite.com http://somesite.com:80
at errnoException (dns.js:27:10)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:78:26)
```

can anyone solve my issue.

Comment: why do you need to specify `http://` ? why not put just `host: 'somesite.com'`

Comment: I tried in chrome Advance REST CLIENT, using this only the service works **http:// somesite.com/path/name** and when i tried **"somesite.com/path/name"** the service not works. so in node js without "http://" its not working. so i need to pass host with "http://". is there any solution, please let me know

Comment: I did not understand what you meant. From the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) you have to specify `http.request({
     host: "somesite.com",
     path: "/path/name/",
     port: 80
     method: "POST"
     ...
})`

Comment: Their example is `var options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST',
 ...
};`

Comment: It's **normal** that with a rest client you have to specify the `http://` like in the address bar. On the other hand, `node` handles adding the `http://` part

Answer (score 2):

The `host` value is to be the host name *only* (the value is resolved by the DNS client and used in the `Host:` HTTP header). In your case this would just be: `host: "somesite.com"`